# How to insert a parameter into the middle of a URL in flutter?

Tags: url, flutter

I have a URL in which the parameters of the url are inserted into the middle:

(i.e, `q=Delhi, IN`
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Delhi,IN&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22 )

Now, in flutter I want to add the parameters dynamically which the user can input the city name, so my query string is :

```
 var queryParameters = {
    'q': cityName
  };

var uri = Uri.http('samples.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/forecast?{}''&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22', queryParameters);
```

but when i execute this code then the query string which i get is

http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast%7B%3F%7D&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22?q=delhi

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add all parameters to the map

```
 var queryParameters = {
    'q': cityName,
    'appid': 'b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22',
  };

 var uri = Uri.http('samples.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/forecast', queryParameters);
```